# How to load content by foreign key?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have two tables A(int Id) and B(int Id, int A_Id)
B has a foreign key to A like B.A_Id -> A.Id
I'm using EF Core.
The db model to B is

```
class B {
  public int Id {set;get;}
  public int A_Id {set;get;}
  public A A {set;get;}
}
```

How could I make EF do read corresponding content from A table by A_id?

Tried put ForeignKeyAttribute over A_Id or A but didn't work.

Comment: Are you using code first approach? Did you checked this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/relationships

Comment: Yes it is code first approach. I'm pretty much familiar with the topic but I'd like to do it with as little coding as possible so I tried attributes.

Comment: Please show the code that actually runs and explain exactly how it doesn't work.

Comment: [Loading Related Data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure the foreign key using attributes as follows

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

public class A
{
    [Key]//primary key
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]//for identity column
    public int Id { set; get; }
}
public class B
{
    [Key]//primary key
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]//for identity column
    public int Id { set; get; }
    public int A_Id { set; get; }//use int? if the column can be set to NULL
    [ForeignKey(nameof(A_Id))]//foreign key
    public A A { set; get; }
}
```

You need to add migration after adding the `Key` attributes